# Plotly chart is not displayed in Shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, plotly

I am trying to implement an option with a drop-down menu in a simple Shiny application. With this drop-down list, you can choose between two charts. The first chart is prepared with the `ggplot2` library, while the second is with the `Plotly` library. Below you can see my code :

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Data
data <- mtcars
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("clusterNum",
  label = h4("Charts"),
  choices = list("Chart1" = "Chart1", "Chart2" = "Chart2"),
  selected = "Chart1"
)
```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart

```{r}
Chart1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

Chart2 <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'bar')


renderPlot({
  switch(input$clusterNum,
    "Chart1" = Chart1,
    "Chart2" = Chart2
  )
})
```
````

After executing this code, I saw that Chart 1, which was prepared with ggplot2, works well, while Chart 2 **with Plotly is not displayed**. So can anybody help me how to solve this problem and to see Chart 2 after selection with the drop-down list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To render the `plotly` chart you have to use `renderPlotly`, while for the ggplot we have to stick with `renderPlot`. As a consequence switching conditionally between the two render functions requires some more effort and involves wrapping in `renderUI` and displaying the chart via `uiOutput`:

````
---
title: "Test App"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)

# Data
data <- mtcars
data$cyl <- as.factor(data$cyl)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("clusterNum",
  label = h4("Charts"),
  choices = list("Chart1" = "Chart1", "Chart2" = "Chart2"),
  selected = "Chart1"
)
```


Column {data-width=650}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### Chart

```{r}
Chart1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
  geom_point()

Chart2 <- plot_ly(data, x = ~wt, y = ~mpg, type = 'bar')
```

```{r}
observeEvent(input$clusterNum, {
  output$plot <- switch(input$clusterNum,
    "Chart1" = renderUI({renderPlot(Chart1)}),
    "Chart2" = renderUI({renderPlotly(Chart2)})
  )
})

uiOutput("plot")
```
````

[image]